# ImageMagick - converting from RAW to PNG brightens the image, but using an online converter doesn't

Tags: imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert, image-conversion

I have a large number of .ARW images that I need to convert to .PNG files for further processing. Using `convert myimage.ARW myimage.png` works, but brightens up the image significantly. How do I convert images in a way that makes it so that the converted image 'looks like' a screenshot of the .ARW image on my MAC?

Comment: See ARW -defines at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php. Perhaps those will help. Otherwise, post an example ARW image that has this issue.

Comment: You likely need to use the -define dng:use-camera-wb=off. It is possibly being enabled automatically when converting to PNG or other formats in Imagemagick.

Comment: @fmw42, I tried using use-camera-wb=off/true, use-auto-wb=false/true, no-auto-bright=true/false, and output-color=0, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. None of them work. Here's the image I'm working with and facing an issue with: https://easyupload.io/eqrh13

The images are Sony ARW images, and using the website https://convertio.co/arw-png/ works perfectly.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I posted to the Imagemagick forum for the raw format experts to review. I will get back to you when I hear back.

Comment: `@requiemman` OK, I found out there was a documentation error on the defines. The following works for me on Imagemagick 7.  `magick -define dng:no-auto-bright=true DNG:DSC04420.ARW DSC04420.png` Unfortunately, it does not seem to work in Imagemagick 6.

Comment: Yep, that's the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @fmw42, the command `magick -define dng:no-auto-bright=true DNG:yourimagefile.extension convertedfilename.extension` does the trick. There is a documentation error with ImageMagick, but this is the general solution.

Comment: The documentation (at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php and at https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php) for the -define had `use-auto-bright` and it should have been and has now been corrected to `no-auto-bright`

Comment: This is now fixed to work in Imagemagick 6.9.12-97 also using the same define.